# Prevent generating resolv.conf on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, pi-hole

I have installed `Pihole` in `docker` for my Ubuntu 18.04 (btw.Jetpack for Jetson Nano) and there was an instructions:

```
Delete the symlink /etc/resolv.conf
rm /etc/resolv.conf

Restart network-manager
sudo service network-manager restart
```

After that my `Pihole` worked, but when I restart my machine I'm getting `resolv.conf` generated again and I have to manually remove it and restart network manager to get `docker` running.
Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Btw. `resolv.conf` is generated by `NetworkManager`

Answer (score 1):

Create a `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/90-dns-none.conf` as desribed in [Redhat docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/manually-configuring-the-etc-resolv-conf-file_configuring-and-managing-networking) with the following content:

```
[main]
dns=none
```

Then:

```
sudo systemctl reload NetworkManager
```

If change isn't applied reboot.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I deleted my old `resolv.conf` , created the file with the settings inside, restarted `NetworkManager` rebooted device, but the `resolv.conf` is there again :(

Comment: but the Verification steps from the site works, when I reload NetworkManager changes i made wont be applied. But it applies it when i reboot

Comment: @MarcelKopera You are right , reloading NM isn't efficient a reboot is required.